Vuejs guard router failed with infinite loop
Hellop, I have a vue3 app consume laravel 11 api, 
I want to develop a router guard to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page. When the Laravel server is not running, the code works and redirects to the login page, but when the server is running, it may cause an infinite loop of requests being sent to the server to check the authenticated user and nothing renders neither the login page nor others :
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const store = useAppStore();
    const authStore = useAuthStore();     
    const isAuthenticated = authStore.currentUser !== null;    
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            if (to.name === 'login') {
                next({ name: 'home' });
            } else next();
            
        } else if (to.name === 'login') {
            next();
        } else {    
            try {
                const response = authStore.getAuthUser();
                console.log(response?.data?.user);

                if (!response?.data?.user) {
                    console.log('not logged'); // le log is shown but it does not reditect to /login and it send infinite requests to authStore.getAuthUser() (/api/user)
                
                    return next({ name: 'login' });
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error during authentication check:', error);
                next({ name: 'login' });
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (to.name === 'login') {
            next({ name: 'home' });
        } else next();
    }
});

can anyone help me !!

There's the same problem as in the previous one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78778875 . It should contain a way to reproduce, currently it isn't, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown what getAuthUser is and where you do requests and how they could possibly affect the way it works. A request is supposed to be asynchronous but there's no await in code you posted

In your try-catch block, is there an error when calling authStore.getAuthUser() function or is the response?.data?.user is null or undefined. This can happen if the try-catch block is always in the catch statement, and it can also happen if if (!response?.data?.user) is always true.
Can you check if there is a message output in the web development mode?

the request  authStore.getAuthUser()  return null

The problem may be that when you request the remote server, the service may not return success. In this case, you can check the server. If there is no error in the server, you can use await authStore.getAuthUser() to execute this code, and then the following code will be executed synchronously。
